# Testing with mocha and browserify

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, browserify, ecmascript-6

I'm writing my project using ES6 and am using bubel + browserify to compile my js files, so far everything works great,

In my gulp file I added a test suites using mocha, like so:

```
gulp.task('buildTestsIndividually', function(done) {
    gutil.log('buildTestsIndividually started');
    glob('./test/**/*.spec.js', function(err, files) {
        gutil.log('files'+files.length);
        if(err) done(err);

        var tasks = files.map(function(entry) {
            return browserify({ entries: [entry] })
                .transform(babelify)
                .bundle()
                .pipe(source(entry))
                .pipe(rename({
                    extname: '.bundle.js'
                }))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(bundledTestsFolder)); 
            });
        es.merge(tasks).on('end', done);
    });
    gutil.log('buildTestsIndividually completed');
});
```

So I want to unit test some of my code, the problem is that my project is using a plugin called froala, and it seems like mocha is not able to load that plugin.

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: this.$el.editable is not a function
          at Array.map (native)
```

Please note that my production env is a copy-paste as the above and the plugin runs there with no problems.

Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: You are importing your application, rooted at your spec file. Are you 100% sure that your spec file properly has `froala` somewhere in its dependencies? Not related, but why are you building a bundle per-spec?

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks, I found the problem and suggested some solutions for it, see my answer below

Comment: But why do you need too bundle each test separately? Normally you'd make a single bundle with everything in it.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I agree, I'm working on creating a single bundle with everything on it. I would love to see how you would implement it with gulp. I don't need each test separately, but that was not the issue though.

Comment: You just pass an array of items to browserify. You're already doing it, but you're doing it with an array of 1 item each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem:
since the task on gulp runs every file separately (with all it's dependencies) yet all the testes are running on the same browser instance, the side effect was that jQuery was loaded multiple times and every time it was overriding the previous jQuery instance and so it the plugins on some test got overridden.

The solution (3 options):

1. make sure that every test has exactly the same plugins extending jquery
2. Gather all the dependencies first (with gulp) then run all the tests (can be over kill)
3. Run each test separately (need to find a way to do it automatically with gulp)

I hope this helps anyone, cheers!